# How do you install & manage TextMate bundles?

Tags: textmate, bundle

In the beginning, there was a canonical SVN repository for TextMate bundles, and the recommended installation unpacked them into a `Pristine Bundles` folder so that TextMate's bundle manager could save your dirty customizations in a separate `Bundles` folder.

Now that nearly everyone's using git, does it still make sense to use `Pristine Bundles`, or is it more appropriate to keep the installed bundle in the `Bundles` folder and manage customizations with git?

What convenience tools are available for discovering, installing, and updating bundles? It seems there's a [getBundle](http://github.com/textmate/getbundle.tmbundle) and a [getBundles](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Review/Bundles/GetBundles.tmbundle/), and no real authoritative way to do it.

I'm starting to think it's probably best to just search GitHub for ".tmbundle" to find the stuff and install it by hand.

Basically, my question is: how do you do it? Is any method better than the others for staying on top of your installed bundles?

Comment: GetBundles (with the 's') seems to be the way most everyone is doing it. However, I do think that if you're anticipating making changes, it'd be best just to grab the git by hand so that you could easily fork it. I believe the built-in bundle editor simply saves the diffs of the changes you make, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Depends on your skill level, you can either download the bundles, then drag and drop them into your Users>my.name>Libary>Application Support>TextMate>Bundles folder, or you can use subversion in terminal like so

```
mkdir -p /Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles
cd /Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles
svn co http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles/Haskell.tmbundle
```

More info you can check out their detailed docs on the TextMate site http://manual.macromates.com/en/bundles

Answer (score 2):

[TextMate 2](https://github.com/textmate/textmate) auto-updates all the default bundles for you!
As a result, GetBundles is deprecated.

This is a massive improvement: adding bundles used to be a big barrier to non-Git-aware users - but no more :-)

*Advanced hint*: If you fork or make your own bundles, these can be maintained using a git client of your choice. Just edit and maintain as usual via git etc. The current location for installs is under the Avian folder, e.g.:

```
`~/Library/Application\ Support/Avian/Bundles/markdown.tmbundle`
```

I think this will change to "Textmate" once TM2 is released

```
`~/Library/Application\ Support/Textmate/Bundles/`
```